What does "Not never, never" mean?
In The Iron Claw (2023), Kevin and Pam are having a romantic moment inside a car:

Kevin: Have you ever?
Pam: What? Why? Why, would that be a problem?
Kevin: What. No. No, no, no. Not at all, no.
Pam: What is it then?
Kevin: I just, uh... I just...
Pam: Honey, never?
Kevin: Not never, never.

What does "Not never, never" mean ?

It means "not 'never' in the strongest sense" or "not 'never' strictly speaking". In other words, at least once.
In general, when we duplicate a word, putting stress on the first copy, we add emphasize but also narrow the meaning.
A classic example among children is this sort of conversation:

— Do you like him?
— Of course I like him.
— No, I mean, do you like like him?

Here the reduplication changes the meaning of "like" from "be fond of" to "be romantically attracted to" or something similar.
Likewise, in your example, "never" is changed from an implied "extremely rarely" to "exactly zero times". This is a joke because it already has this supposedly more intense meaning. Kevin is being coy by implying that he was formerly using "never" less strictly than that.
